# How to clear/remove default DateTime NULL value in bound Gridview row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, date-formatting

This is my bound field in GridView:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date On Hold" DataField="HoldOn" DataFormatString="{0:MM-dd-yyyy}"  />
```

It is displaying "01-01-0001" if date is NULL in Database. I don't want to show anything in that case.

How can I do this ?

Comment: You should use `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` to store `HoldOn`. A null value will be formatted as an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

You could try a TemplateField instead with a short hand if else:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date On Hold">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# (DateTime)Eval("HoldOn") == DateTime.MinValue ? string.Empty : string.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", (DateTime)Eval("HoldOn")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that sanity check in [Gridview's RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event. Something like this:

```
private GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        YourObject dataObj = e.Row.DataItem as YourObj;
        Label lbl = e.Row.FindControl("lblDate") as Label;
        if(lbl != null)
        {
             DateTime myDate;
             if (DateTime.TryParse(dataObj["HoldOn"].ToString(),out myDate))
                lbl.Text = myDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
             else 
                lbl.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```